# How do I style an ASP.NET HTML server control by ID?

Tags: css, asp.net

When I create an `HTML server control` in ASP.NET 4.5 with an `ID` and use `CSS` to style that `ID`, it fails. When I inspect the source of the `ASPX` page, it shows that `ASP.NET` has changed my control's `ID`. In this instance...

```
<div id="PasswordStatus" class="well well-sm" runat="server">
  Current
</div>
```

...becomes...

```
<div id="article_PasswordStatus" class="well well-sm">
  Current
</div>
```

Can I then reliably (and with best practices in mind) just create the `CSS` style for `#article_PasswordStatus` instead? Or should I create a one-use `CSS` class for it, something like...

```
<div id="PasswordStatus" class="well well-sm password-status">
  Current
</div>
```

Preferably, can I still somehow use the original ID I assigned?

**Note**: I do **not** want to convert this to a Web server control.

Comment: what asp.net version you're using?

Comment: How do you add styles ?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I'm running ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming .net 4 and greater, you can use [`ClientIDMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your HTML would be like this

```
<div id="PasswordStatus" class="well well-sm" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    Current
</div>
```

When using `Static` the ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Add in the `ClientIDMode="Static"` option to ensure your client Ids do not change.
Information can be found [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40).

```
<div id="PasswordStatus" class="well well-sm" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    Current
</div>
```

This option forces the control’s ClientID to use its ID value directly. No naming container naming at all is applied and you end up with clean client ids

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a best practice to use classes for css styling instead of IDs. You can avoid problems like this, reuse your css and so on, so that would be the path I'd choose.

ID in asp.net (webforms) can be modified in various ways and I wouldn't rely on that personally.

Comment: Not so much an answer to my main question, though I appreciate the perspective on best practices

Comment: @skia.heliou, how come? You asked how to style an element (class vs id) and I've replied your best bet is to use a class for multiple reasons. Relying on asp.net webforms ID generation isn't wise as it was a subject to change in the past.

Comment: My main question is how to use ID's for HTML server controls; the best practices part was secondary. I see the value in your viewpoints, but when I posted the question it was about using an ID, regardless of how my styling strategy may change in the future.